# How to disable automatic file extension and force writing to existing file with 7z?

Tags: 7zip

This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
TEMP_ZIP_NAME="$(tempfile)"
ZIP_NAME="${NOW}-views.tar.7z"
tar c -C /srv/partybus.com views public_html/css 2>> "${CRONLOG}" \
    | 7z a -si "${TEMP_ZIP_NAME}" 2>> "${CRONLOG}"
```

But there's 2 problems:

1. 7z keeps adding a `.7z` extension to my temporary filename which breaks my subsequent commands
2. Even if I use `tempfile -s .7z` instead, 7z gets upset because the 0-byte tempfile is not a valid archive.

How can I force 7z to just overwrite the temp file as-is?

Answer (score 1):

to skip the extension just append a dot at the end of the file-name: e.g. `7z files "myzip."`